# Python replace list elements with Nan if they contain a-z characters

Tags: python, list, character

I'd appreciate some help with the following syntax with I receive the below error for

```
    for x in price:

    if x.find(re(['^A-Za-z0-9'],x)):
        x = ''
    price1.append(x)
```

I'm essentially trying to determine if a list element contains the characters a-z and if so I would like to replace the entire element with a blank value so I can drop it later

price is a list

error is

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

price list = `['\nRRP\n£13,315\n', '\n£12,815\n', '\nSave\n£500\n', '£1,500', '£950', '£1,400', '£760', '£1,500', '£999', '£995', '£2,000', '£1,499', '£907', '£10,499', '£5,495']`
 
Thanks

Comment: This seems to be unvalid code, you can call `re` like this, please add some elements and detils

Comment: `re` is a module and is not callable. Perhaps you mean `if re.search('[^A-Za-z0-9]', x):`